# Using DCount for more than one domain in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am basically trying to count the number of occurences of Item A IF the value of Item B is ='string'.

I have been doing it like this- which turns up an error:

DCount("[Item A]", "[Table]", "[Item A] > 1 and [Item B] = 'apples'")

Unfortunaltey, B is in a different table, so MS Access doesn't recognize it when I run the query. What else can I do?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` the two tables.  `DCount` is "Domain" Count.  Domain is basically the values that fall under a single field/column in a single table/query, hence the restriction to a single table.  The simplest way to resolve this I think would be to make a new query that joins both tables, making both `item a` and `item b` accessible from the same place:

```
SELECT [item a], [item b]
FROM [Table] AS t
INNER JOIN [Other Table] AS ot
    ON t.itemID = ot.itemID
```

Obviously I don't know the name of your other table, or the names of the fields you would need to do the join on (specified by `ON` in that query), so replace field and table names where appropriate.  So, say I named that query "productA-B", your DCount usage would look like:

```
DCount("[item a]", "productA-B", "[item a] > 1 AND [item b] = 'apples'")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time since i used acceess, but can you not prefix `[Item B]` with the table name? i.e. `[other_table].[Item B]`